# How to combine and validate predictions for two sklearn random forest classifiers?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, sparse-matrix, random-forest

Sklearn random forest trees take too much memory(~100mb per tree on my dataset) to store many of them in RAM.

Can I simply average probabilities, returned from several rf[i].predict_proba() calls, or is there need for more complicated merge operation?

Is there any way to get oob_score for whole ensemble?

(I've seen some answers that concatenate rf.estimators_ lists but they do not work for me because I can't keep all estimators in RAM and wish to discard them after calling predict_proba)

Comment: How big is your dataset? (number of samples and number of features)

Comment: 100000 samples, 2000 features, sparse matrix. I suspect this might be related to me using 40 processors(I read that sklearn does some redundant copying in such case), but this does not change my problem much :)